# What current transformer do I need?

Tags: meter

I have a Prime Instruments model 60-579 watt meter for a gas generator. It has a scale of 0 to 3750 watts and is marked 125 volts. So its for a 30 amp circuit. I have searched extensively for the current transformer to use with this meter but no one seems to know. Does anyone know which CT is needed or how to calculate which one would be needed. FWIW, I measured .2 to .4 ohms across the meter terminals. Thanks

Here is a picture inside the meter. The wire is less than 14 gauge.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z72437v21uvgnxh/PrimerMeter%20Turns.jpg?dl=0

The wire in the turns around the disk is less than 14 gauge. I am concerned about running 30 amps thru the meter.

Comment: Link to user manual?

Comment: Can' find one those either.

Comment: What did https://www.primeinstruments.com/contact.html say when you asked them?

Comment: They didn't reply to 2 emails.

Comment: Most meters have an input of 5A, with 0.3 ohm input it likely to be the case. Connect your meter to mains or secondary of a transformer and a known load that will give 1-2 Amps and see if your meter reads the proportional reading. Look for a CT that gives 5A at the full scale of your meter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Image source: [All Electronics](https://www.allelectronics.com/mas_assets/media/allelectronics2018/pdf/meters.pdf).*

Judging by this catalog extract and various other images on the web it is a two terminal meter so it is really only an ammeter with a scale calibrated to indicate power drawn from a 125 V supply with a resistive load. The non-linear scale is due to the square term in *P = I<sup>2</sup>R* but it may be compounded if the meter movement is moving iron type. If your voltage deviates from 125 V the power reading will not reflect this. I'd consider the meter as "confirming a hunch" rather than as an accurate instrument.

I suspect that you just connect it in series with the load. No current transformer. Inspect it to assess whether or not you think the internal wiring is capable of 30 A and try it with a 1 kW load - a kettle or heater.

Comment: You were correct. I put the meter in series and it closely read the watts. No CT is needed for this meter.